# How do I select a summed range of columns from MySQL within a 24 hour period?

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have a significant amount of data in which I am trying to calculate the sum of one column based on occurrences within a 24 hour period.

The table is as follows:

```
ID          Customer    LOCATION  FROM_DATETIME     TO_DATETIME       Amount    24Revenue

23100470    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-23 23:40    2014-03-24 00:00    8.20    26.65
23111106    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 07:06    2014-03-24 07:26    0.00    22.14
23111865    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 07:27    2014-03-24 07:30    0.00    22.14
23112909    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 07:56    2014-03-24 08:06    3.69    22.14
23122768    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 11:38    2014-03-24 11:46    3.28    18.45
23125519    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 12:35    2014-03-24 12:38    1.23    15.17
23126385    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 12:53    2014-03-24 13:00    2.87    13.94
23141213    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-24 19:58    2014-03-24 20:16    7.38    11.07
23155172    Customer01  Idaho   2014-03-25 06:52    2014-03-25 07:01    3.69    3.69
23165719    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 10:52    2014-03-25 13:34    44.97   70.21
23173857    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 13:36    2014-03-25 13:43    2.87    25.24
23174971    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 14:00    2014-03-25 14:04    1.64    22.37
23176607    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 14:40    2014-03-25 14:52    4.51    20.73
23178488    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 15:24    2014-03-25 16:04    0.00    16.22
23181743    Customer02  Idaho   2014-03-25 16:42    2014-03-25 17:45    16.22   16.22
```

At this time I am choosing a data set for a period of 1 week:

```
SELECT ID, Customer, from_datetime, to_datetime, location 
WHERE to_datetime BETWEEN '2014-03-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-31' 
AND location='Idaho';
```

This query returns $recordset.

Then using that dataset witin PHP, I am looping through each record and then querying the database again to sum the revenue column for all records with the same plate and that occurred within 24 hours of that time:

```
foreach ($recordset as $key => $value) {

$fromdate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($rsRentals[$key]['to_datetime']));

$todate=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromdate)) . " +24 hours");


SELECT SUM(amount) as revenue WHERE plate='$recordset[$key]['plate']'
AND location = 'Idaho' AND to_datetime >= '$fromdate' AND from_datetime < '$todate'

}
```

My issue is that based on my calculations (50 sums within 2 minutes), it will take approximately 13-14 hours to sum ~20000 records.  This is way too long and I think there must be a simpler way to run this query with a JOIN or something, but my attempts have failed.  Above is the only setup that I have been able to do with success, albeit a limited dataset.

Does anyone have suggestions on what I could do to obtain the same result but a much quicker and efficient query?

Comment: Please format the code and sql table in your question. What you posted lacks formatting and is very rough to read.

Comment: Thanks.  I had just realized it posted plain text and was about to update it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use the first query to grab the list of plates,

then insert that as a subquery to a bigger query where your plate is your group by and your where in the outer querty is where time is between TO_DATETIME and TO_DATETIME-24

Comment: Ok, I'm getting what you're saying but not able to replicate it.  I thought that was what I was doing to begin with but I see that I query every single time whereas I believe you're saying to run it once, just a massive query.  Any chance you can represent the query you are referring to?

Comment: I should clarify that the 24Revenue column is the result I am looking for, for each query.  Essentially, I want to see how much revenue that customer generated within the 24 hour period of that specific transaction(amount).

Comment: I should clarify that the plate column is actually named customer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried the following query with no success:

SELECT SUM(amount) AS revenue FROM `rentaldetails`
WHERE to_datetime BETWEEN '2014-03-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-25' AND id = (SELECT id FROM `rentaldetails` 
WHERE to_datetime BETWEEN '2014-03-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-31' 
AND location='Idaho') GROUP BY id;